# Change the Default movement of the DragDecorator in ListBoxDragDropTarget

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, drag-and-drop, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using a ListBoxDragDropTarget from the Silverlight Toolkit and i want to change the movement of an item when it's dragged. So in my ListBox Panel it should only can moveable inside the Panel and only vertical movement should be allowed not horizontal.

As by default you can move the items from ListBox over the whole Application and i don't wnat that it should only be moveable in the ListBox.

So what i tried was to change the RenderTransform of the PopupControl and the DragDecoratorControl and even the Canvas inside the Template.

```
public class FixedListBoxDragDropTarget : ListBoxDragDropTarget
{
    public Popup DragPopupControl { get; set; }
    public DragDecorator DragDecoratorControl { get; set; }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        DragPopupControl = GetTemplateChild(DragPopupName) as Popup;
        DragDecoratorControl = GetTemplateChild(DragDecoratorName) as DragDecorator;
    }
}
```

On the ListBoxItems a have attached the MouseMove Event

```
private void TopicUsedControl_MouseMove_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Get the Control
    var dragDropPanel = UIHelper.FindChild<FixedListBoxDragDropTarget>(Application.Current.RootVisual, "DragDropControl");

    var transform = dragDropPanel.DragPopupControl.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    var transformDragdecorator = dragDropPanel.DragDecoratorControl.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform;
    if (transform == null && transformDragdecorator == null)
    {
        transform = new CompositeTransform();
        transformDragdecorator = new CompositeTransform();
        dragDropPanel.DragPopupControl.RenderTransform = transform; //PopupControl of Template
        dragDropPanel.DragPopupControl.Child.RenderTransform = transform; //Canvas inside the Template
        dragDropPanel.DragDecoratorControl.RenderTransform = transformDragdecorator; // Dragdecorator of Template
    }

    transform.TranslateX = 0;
    transform.TranslateY = 10;
    transformDragdecorator.TranslateX = 0;
    transformDragdecorator.TranslateY = 10;
}
```

I have tried to set the RenderTranform to Fixed values that the control does not move anymore to test it. But it happens nothing i can move the control with the mouse and the code above does not have any effect.

How can I change or rather override the default movement behaviour of the dragdecorator?